# How to remove 'via' in email sent by PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer for email sending, I am wondering how could I remove 'via page domain' in received email?

Example:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: That's not something PHPMailer controls. It's related to how the mailserver is configured and how the mail is routed. You see this a lot in gmail emails, nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: "gmail via" typed into Google, leads to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en#zippy=,i-see-via-and-a-website-name-next-to-the-senders-name in no time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "via" information from emails not sent through Gmail
Gmail checks whether the messages you send are authenticated.

If you send messages with a bulk mailing vendor or third party affiliates, prevent your emails from being blocked by Gmail.

Publish an SPF record that includes the IPs of the vendor or affiliates which send your messages.

Sign your messages with a DKIM signature that is associated with your domain.
Make sure the domain in the "From:" address matches the domain you're using to authenticate your emails.

More about it here:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en#zippy=%2Ci-see-via-and-a-website-name-next-to-the-senders-name